# Changing the backcolor of selected text in the WebBrowser control

Tags: .net, winforms, winapi, webbrowser-control

In Chrome whether the text color is dark or light, if you select it with your mouse, it always appears white on a blue background.

**The WebBrowser control behaves differently if the text color is dark or light**.

- If the text is dark, same as Chrome.
- But if the text color is light, yellow for instance, the selected text becomes Royal Blue on a **White background** making it difficult to see the beginning and the end of the selection if the background of the page is white (as it is in my winform app).

Is there a way (I am thinking using WinApi, maybe) to change the selected text background color?

Comment: Have a look at the [feature control registry keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330720(v=vs.85).aspx#featuresDH). There might be something that controls exactly this behaviour. Otherwise try to set [`FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730(v=vs.85).aspx#browser_emulation) to use a higher version. The behaviour might be version dependent. By default the browser control uses an old version for compatibility.

Comment: Thx. The behaviour is the same in the latest version of IE.